# Change Splash Screen Color Programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, drawable, oncreate, splash-screen

I use following the way to change splash screen color programmatically, but DrawableLayer's `FindDrawableLayerById` returns a null value.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundleSavedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundleSavedInstanceState);

                LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.XMLFileSplashScreen);

                GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)layerDrawable.FindDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.itemSplashScreenColor);

                gradientDrawable.SetColor(Resource.Color.Blue);
            }
```

Comment: Please show your `XMLFileSplashScreen` file, and is there any error? NullPointException?

Comment: Hi, have you solved your question? Could you please show your `XMLFileSplashScreen` file? So I will help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem solved by this:

```
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layer-list` with `<item android:drawable=”@color/colorPrimary” />` as described [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)

Comment: My mean is programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linear or Relative Layout set background Color like this in your oncreate method:

```
LinearLayout chglayout = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.layout.the_id);
chglayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final FrameLayout frm = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.FramId);

frm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {        
        frm.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorEndBlue));
    }
});
```